# Django basics: how to render a context with a class based view

Tags: django, django-templates, django-class-based-views

My 'Note' model has a Charfield called 'tags'. I want to take the Note.tags string and render it as a . I have a method that will give me a python list and I am sort of hoping that I can use the form method '.as_ul' in the template. But I can't seem to get the variable into the template. Here is what I am trying:

My view class:

```
import string
...

class NoteDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Note
    template_name = 'note_taker/note'

    def tag_string_to_list(self):
        tag_string = Note.tags
        tag_list = string.split(tag_string)
        return render(template_name, Context({'tag_list':tag_list}, note_taker))
```

My template:

```
<ul>
  {{ tag_list.as_ul }}
</ul>
```

even if I am wrong about how to use '.as_ul' I can't even render the list with {{ tag_list }}

I suppose I am not understanding how view methods work then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `get_context_data` method.

```
class NoteDetailView(generic.DetailView):

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(NoteDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['tag_list'] = Note.tags.split()
        return context
```

Within the template, you won't be able to use `.as_ul`, but there is a built in filter [`unordered_list`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#unordered-list) that will probably do what you want:

```
<ul>
    {{ tag_list|unordered_list }}
</ul>
```

Although you should really consider defining a standalone `Tag` model and using a many-to-many relationship rather than just a char field.  This is one of the classic examples of many-to-many relationships.  Or using one of the third-party Django tagging packages.

Comment: Thanks! Yes I shall eventually make a Tag model but I wanted to solve this problem first because it was bugging me.

Answer (score 0):

I always use Django's standard `ContextMixin`. It makes sure that the view object is available in the template as `view`.

So the view becomes like

```
class NoteDetailView(generic.ContextMixin, generic.DetailView):
    model = Note
    template_name = 'note_taker/note'

    def tag_string_as_list(self):
        return Note.tags.split()
```

And in the view you do:

```
<ul>{{ view.tag_string_as_list }}</ul>
```